# Как создать ссылку на файл pdf на сервере node + express

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

У меня есть простой сервер на node.js и express, задеплоенный на heroku, привязанный к аккаунту на github. Обработка статических файлов происходит с помощью метода static таким образом:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './app/assets')));
```

Соответственно, когда я добавляю изображение на github, сервер отдает это изображение по пути: host/assets/имя_изображения, например - https://obscure-everglades-20808.herokuapp.com/assets/ml212.jpeg

Я надеялась, что и pdf файлы я смогу обрабатывать также, но это не работает. Как мне реализовать "отдачу" pdf файлов? Чтобы на фронте пользователь мог или открыть, или скачать его? То есть как сделать саму кнопку для скачивания на фронте я понимаю, как сделать, чтобы сервер их отдавал?

Comment: добавьте свой pdf в папку статическую, а на фронте укажите ссылку для скачивания или открытия в новом окне. Обратите внимание, у вас создан префикс виртуального пути '/assets'

Comment: Так я добавила, так же, как и jpeg:  https://obscure-everglades-20808.herokuapp.com/assets/ml212.pdf , они в одной папке лежат. При этом jpeg нормально открывается, а pdf - Cannot GET /assets/ml212.pdf. То есть тут какая-то доп обработка нужна с помощью express

Comment: не удалось получить доступ - точно путь верный?

Comment: Путь верный, доступ не удается получить, потому что мой сервер не отдает такой  тип файлов(( недостаточно модуля express static

Comment: не совсем понял вас - express без проблем дает ссылку на файлы пдф